# Quicksort Array Code

Tags: java, exception, quicksort

```
public class Main
{

  public static void main (String args[])
  {
    int nums[]= {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1};
    for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
      System.out.print("  " +nums[index]);;
    System.out.println();

    quickSort(nums,0,9);
    for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
      System.out.print("  " +nums[index]);
    System.out.println();
  }


  private static void swap(int a[], int lft, int rt)
  {
    int temp;
    temp = a[lft];
    a[lft] = a[rt];
    a[rt] = temp;
  }


  public static int pivot(int firstpl, int lastpl)
  {
    if(firstpl >= lastpl)
      return -1;
    else
      return firstpl;
  }



  private static void quickSort(int a[], int first, int last)
  {
    int left,right;  
    int pivindex = pivot(first,last);
    if(pivindex >= 0)
    {
      left = pivindex +1;
      right = last;
      do
      {
        while ( a[left] < a[pivindex] && left <= right )
          left++;
        while (a[right] > a[pivindex])
          right--;
        if (right > left)
          swap(a,left,right);
      }
      while(left < right);

       swap (a, pivindex, right);
       quickSort( a, first, right-1);
       quickSort(a, right+1, last);

    }
  }      
}
```

That is the code for a quick sort. Everything works right if the array's 0 position number is "2" but if it is anything else, it throws an exception.

For example, if I put this in for array:

5  6  8  9  7  8  0  1  8  2

It gives the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at Main.quickSort(Main.java:48)
    at Main.quickSort(Main.java:59)
    at Main.quickSort(Main.java:59)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

Please help!

Comment: what's wrong with using Arrays.sort(int[] nums) ?

Comment: Note that the lists [5  2  3  4  6  7  8  9  0  1] and [ 5  6  3  9  7  8  0  1  8  2] both sort w/o error.  Maybe the problem has to do with having duplicates?

Comment: It seems that the error is with the first number of the array being less than the last number in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that `first = 8` and `last = 9` in one of the calls to `quickSort()`. Suppose also that a[8] > a[9]. Think about what will happen in the `left++` loop...

(Remember, the `a[left] < a[pivindex]` part of the condition is checked before the `left <= right` part)

OK, try walking through the method:

Starting with first = 8, last = 9, I end up with pivindex = 8, left = 9, right = 9. I check the while condition:

```
while(a[9] < a[8] && 9 <= 9)
```

It's true, so I increment left. Now left = 10 and right = 9. I check the while condition again...

```
while(a[10] < a[8] && 10 <= 9)
```

... and go off the end of the array. Now, if only I had checked that 10 <= 9 before looking at a[left]!

OK, if you're still stuck I'll just come right out and tell you. The problem in that loop is that you are trying to access `a[left]` **before** checking if `left` is too big. You can fix the problem in one of two ways:

1. Switch the order of the conditions, so that you check left first, or
2. Change the <= to a <, so that `left` never gets bigger than `right`.

Comment: The code fails when the first number in the array is smaller than the last one. I need help on that.

Comment: @user: OK, I went ahead and gave you the answer because you still seemed to be stuck. Sorry if that was aggravating; it looked like an exercise so I thought you might appreciate some hints to help you figure it out on your own.

Comment: Zahniser, I changed the left <= right to left < right but now it doesn't compile right because it just keeps compiling and the result doesn't come out.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is a simple one: you're inadvertently trying to access a 10-element array with index of `10`, when the only valid indexes are 0-9.

This is happening on line #48 (or possibly 47, or 49). You're probably accidentally adding +1 to an index when you don't realize it, and exceeding the bounds of the array.

Figure out why your special case is happening, and you'll be home.

Comment: "*There are only two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.*"

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. If I remove a +1 from any of the lines that have one, it continues to crash.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that on line #48, as pointed out by the error you posted, you're inadvertently referencing the array with `[10]` instead of some number between 0-9. You have to track down the source of that. Could be helpful to go into debug mode in your IDE and step through the code, to see what it's doing, and how it gets to the point.

Comment: is there any way we can get this on chat @normalocity? I know I am taking your time but it is hard for me as I am fairly new to Java. I would really appreciate if you could help me on chat.

Comment: Well, I can't really jump into that right now, but if you want to email me at the email address in my profile, I might be able to help a little more. The short answer is, use your debugger. If you're new to Java, or debugging tools in general, then this is going to be a long discussion (so be prepared), and something I'd personally rather do over email.

Comment: @normalocity +1 from me for answer and offering to help someone out by e-mail when you don't have to. Need more people like you in this community!